# Navbar collapse button only expands (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've already seen a lot of topics about this kind of problem but never this one: when collapsed, I can hit the button to expand the list of links, that's cool, but when I want to close it by clicking again on it, it doesn't work and it remains open.

Also, I paid attention to stuff like data-target and stuff

Here is my button :

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

And here is my collapsed navbar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="/">doc</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">about</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: it's working find..check this:  https://jsfiddle.net/tanp7wg7/

Comment: Your code seems to work, [here is](https://jsfiddle.net/3hv9fgqw/) the JSFiddle for it.

Comment: he missed some scripts to include i guess

Comment: This is why I don't understand guys, anywhere it is supposed to work but not on my server. About the scripts, I have jquery and the ones provided by Bootstrap (With jquery on top) and still doesn't work

Comment: inspect your webpage, check your console, it supposed to work, there is no other way around

Comment: I can say, I had an issue like this, it was because i was importing both 'cdn' links. 
....bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js and
....bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css. 

I thought I needed both, but near the top of the page here [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/javascript/) it has a short note saying to use JS.min, or JS, not both. Which is weird that removing it fixed it, I was under the assumption I needed both JS package and the CSS package. One for the CSS and one for the JS magic. This collapse thing seems to be CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your version of Bootstrap If it's not latest one then please try to change your version to latest and then just check again,

And also check your jquery version. It should be the latest one to avoid conflict.

I have checked your code with the latest version of Bootstrap and it's working properly.

Thanks.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="/">doc</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```